# Complete unit testing example in play framework + DI

Tags: scala, unit-testing, playframework-2.4, playframework-2.5

I am looking for complete example of unit test for play 2.4 application + DI.
The idea is very simple:

1. We have application.test.conf from which I want to read the configuration data, run evolutions etc.
2. Then I want to inject instance of class which uses DI, example:

   class UserBean @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider, implicit val configuration: Configuration, cacheApi: CacheApi) {

   }
3. Then call methods of injected object and test it.

The problem that I faced described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37192401/inject-my-bean-like-class-to-test-play-2-4 but nobody answers my question.
Appreciate any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The Java properties have the highest precedence for loading a conf file with [TypeSafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior). You can tell the sbt to use different config file when running the tests:

   `javaOptions in Test += "-Dconfig.resource=" + System.getProperty("config.resource", "application.test.conf")`
2. You can create your test Application with GuiceBuilder, see [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTestingWithGuice#Testing-with-Guice).
   Note that you must have a running app in your test, like:

   `val myTestApp = new GuiceApplicationBuilder()
         .overrides(bind[Component].to[MockComponent])
         .build

   "my test" in running(myTestApp) { ... }`

And then you can use injector, like this:

```
val app2MyDao = play.api.Application.instanceCache[MyDAO]
val myDAO: MyDAO = app2MyDao(myTestApp)
```

You can also use the ScalaTest's traits like OneAppPerSuite and override it's fake app.

**EDIT**: I've made a simple [project](https://github.com/sake92/PlayGuiceExample) to demonstrate what I wanted to show.

Comment: I get the idea from documentation, but it is not working, I am looking for some working example.

Comment: I have the following exception:

uncaught exception when running beans.RemoteSystemBeanSpec: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: play.utils.Reflect$.bindingsFromConfiguration(Lplay/api/Environment;Lplay/api/PlayConfig;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Lplay/utils/Reflect$SubClassOf;Lplay/utils/Reflect$SubClassOf;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;Lscala/reflect/ClassTag;)Lscala/collection/Seq;
sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: play.utils.Reflect$.bindingsFromConfiguration(Lplay/api/Environment;Lplay

Comment: You are probably using some old library/plugin. Or, you maybe compiled your classes against a different version of a library(that doesn't have that referenced method) etc... Try to run `sbt clean` and then `sbt compile`. Also, try to use libraries that are up to date.